# What script to use if I want to examine .bashrc file. In other words, to know if it is in use or not?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

Does anyone know if it is possible to use a script for printing to the screen that `.bashrc` is in use or not.

I found `.bashrc` under home directory, but is there any script which can print the status of the file, like it is open, in use and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- You want only to check if a file is being accessed *now* in any manner
- You want to monitor a file for changes, like keeping a continuous watch

---

**For case 1:**

You can use `fuser` or `lsof`, these are the common tools for this:

```
lsof ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
fuser ~/.bashrc
```

Check `man lsof` and `man fuser`

---

**For case 2:**

If you want to have a continuous check, Linux provides `inotify` family of system calls to monitor any filesystem events.

So you can add a continuous watch by the `-m` (`--monitor`) option of `inotifywait`:

```
inotifywait -m ~/.bashrc
```

From here, you can take actions e.g. run a command if a specific event e.g. read or write takes place.

There are also many options and use cases, take a look at `man inotifywait`. You might need to install `inotify-tools` first.

Comment: @heemyal for sure! :)

Answer (score 0):

Read `man bash`, and learn that `.bashrc` is read, processed, and closed when a shell starts (read the `man` page for more detail). However, you could `sudo lsof $HOME/.bashrc` in a terminal window to see if any process has the file open at the moment.

Comment: I know that .bashrc is read and processed when a shell opens. Thank you for trying to help, and not just typing 'read' this and 'read' that.